# How to select the exponential decay constant for weighting in proc logistic?

Tags: logistic, sas, exponential-distribution, exponential-smoothing, overfitting

I am trying to predict the sales conversion using proc logistics in SAS. Right now I have around 3 months of data, and it will gradually grow to more than an year over time. My intuition is that the most recent data is a better predictor of the event, and hence I want to weight the data using the exponential weighting method.

For this I have two questions:

1. How do I select an optimum decay constant for the exponential weighting? Is there a scientific way to go about it instead of just trial and error?
2. As my data grows larger, is there a way to ensure that exponential weighting changes or remains optimized? This may also cause overfitting.

I tried searching this on the forum but could not find an explanation in this context. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: any comments or suggestions ?